# How to get list of all registered DS names (Object) in JBoss programmatically?

Tags: java, jboss

I want to check if same schema registered with two different DS name in JBoss, So

How to get list of all registered DS names (Object) in JBoss programmatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can list **all** Objects bound to the JBoss (JNDI) via following method:

```
Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
NamingEnumeration<NameClassPair> namedEnum = initCtx.list("java:comp/env");
```

Then afterwards you may filter by `className` in `NameClassPair`

See [API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/naming/Context.html#list%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 2):

By using JNDI, something like this.

```
Context context = new InitialContext();
context.listBindings("java:comp/env");
```

Comment: Which type of object in list return by listBindings? With above, can I get it's DS URL?

Comment: with `listBindings` you will get the bound objects as well. I think that is not important if you only want to see, which objects are bound. But still a good answer ;o)