# How to get JBOSS'S datasources programmatically

Tags: java, jboss

I am using JBOSS 7.0 application server. I have declared my datasources in standalone.xml as follows,

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ltmsfleettrackingds" pool-name="ltmsfleettrackingdspool" enabled="true" jta="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
                <connection-url>
                    jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fleettrackingdb?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf-8
                </connection-url>
                <driver>
                    mysqldriver
                </driver>
                <transaction-isolation>
                    TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
                </transaction-isolation>
                <pool>
                    <min-pool-size>
                        10
                    </min-pool-size>
                    <max-pool-size>
                        50
                    </max-pool-size>
                    <prefill>
                        true
                    </prefill>
                    <use-strict-min>
                        false
                    </use-strict-min>
                    <flush-strategy>
                        FailingConnectionOnly
                    </flush-strategy>
                </pool>
                <security>
                    <user-name>
                        root
                    </user-name>
                    <password>

                    </password>
                </security>
                <validation>
                    <validate-on-match>
                        false
                    </validate-on-match>
                    <background-validation>
                        false
                    </background-validation>
                    <useFastFail>
                        false
                    </useFastFail>
                </validation>
                <statement>
                    <prepared-statement-cache-size>
                        100
                    </prepared-statement-cache-size>
                    <share-prepared-statements/>
                </statement>
            </datasource>
```

Is it possible to get the mentioned datasource jndi name declared in standalone.xml programmatically in java language.

Comment: yes, it's possible. Just iterate the JNDI namespace.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get list of all registered DS names (Object) in JBoss programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759428/how-to-get-list-of-all-registered-ds-names-object-in-jboss-programmatically)